# meaning: go on Ving

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

The following is taken from the classic novel *The Count of Monte Cristo*. Normally, I'd expect "go on Ving" to mean an action or state is going on without interruption. But here, it seems to mean "resume sleeping after an interruption." Is this an outdated usage, or is my understanding incorrect? Or is the author in error?

> From time to time, however, shaken by a jolt which was harder than the rest, Danglars would momentarily re-open his eyes and feel himself carried along at the same speed through the same Roman campagna, among a scattering of broken aqueducts which looked like granite giants petrified as they ran. But the night was cold, dark and rainy, and it was far better for a man who was half asleep to stay at the back of the coach, with his eyes closed, than to put his head out of the door and ask where he was – from a postilion whose only answer would be: ‘Non capisco.’ So Danglars **went on sleeping**, thinking that it would be time enough to wake up when they arrived at the relay.

Answer (score 1):

Note *Danglars would momentarily re-open his eyes* and *half asleep.* The sense seems to be that he was drowsy, and chose to let himself stay in that state rather than to make himself wake up properly.

Comment: If someone is drowsy, are they sleeping?

Comment: @Apollyon -  I wouldn't have said so - neither could he think while asleep -  but (if that's a literal translation) that is presumably what Dumas meant. Danglars allowed himself to remain in a somnolent state.